# How to save byte[] using a procedure?

Tags: sql-server, telerik, telerik-open-access

This stored procedure does not save the data, it seems to be a problem with the `VARBINARY`. I am passing a `byte[]` to it, but then it doesn't work. If I send this parameter as `NULL` it works.

I'm calling the procedure with the following code:

```
public Community AddCommunity(string name, string description, byte[] picture, User owner, int? venue, int communityID) 
{
    using (var database = new Database())
    {
        return database.Scope.GetSqlQuery<Community>("QP_AddCommunity ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?", "VARCHAR Name, VARCHAR Description, VARBINARY Picture, INTEGER Owner, INTEGER Venue, INTEGER ID").GetResult(name, description, picture, owner.ID, venue, communityID);
    }
}
```

The procedure is the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[QP_AddCommunity]
    @Name VARCHAR(120),
    @Description VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Picture VARBINARY(MAX),
    @Owner INTEGER,
    @Venue INTEGER,
    @ID INTEGER

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM QT_Community WHERE ID = @ID) = 0
        INSERT INTO QT_Community(Name, [Description], Picture, [Owner], Venue) VALUES(@Name, @Description, @Picture, @Owner, @Venue);

    ELSE
        UPDATE QT_Community SET Name = @Name, [Description] = @Description, Picture = @Picture, [Owner] = @Owner, Venue = @Venue WHERE ID = @ID;

    SELECT * FROM QT_Community WHERE ID = @@IDENTITY;


END
```

What's wrong with this code? Isn't `VARBINARY` a `byte[]` ?

---

This code works when executing on SQL Server Management Studio.

```
DECLARE @X varbinary(20)
Set @X = CAST('Testing' As varbinary(20))
EXECUTE [QP_AddCommunity] 'aaaaa', 'descricao', @X, 216, NULL, 0;
```

But when calling from the `GetSqlQuery` method with something on the `byte[]` the transaction says it's not active and not dirty. BUT if the `byte[]` is `null` it works as it should.

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'. Do you get an error? Does the insert/update work but the picture is missing? Does the insert/update work and the picture is corrupted? btw, code that checks for COUNT(*) and then inserts or updates is broken under concurrency. You should use `MERGE` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Where is the `CommandParameter`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found that it is impossible as [this answer](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/databases/how-to-store-byte-array-into-sql-server-image-datetype-using-orm.aspx#851762) shows

> Hello gaurav, currently our
>   GetSqlQuery method cannot operate
>   properly with parameters of type
>   LongVarBinary or VarBinary, thus
>   making it impossible for the stored
>   procedure to work as expected.  We are
>   aware of this problem and we are
>   working on fixing it. As a work around
>   you should try and use Linq to achieve
>   your goal. Greetings, Petar the
>   Telerik team

Answer (score 1):

Accordingly to [this table](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/fields-mapping-simple-field.html) it seems either `BLOB`, `BINARY`, `VARBINARY` would be valid types for `[] of primitive type`.

You could try to [ask on their forums](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/development.aspx), maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: i have already asked here http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm/development/save-image-with-procedure.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [.WRITE method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t%28VS.80%29.aspx). On your INSERT, insert 0x for Picture, then update independently.

```
UPDATE QT_Community 
    SET Picture.Write (@Picture, 0, DATALENGTH(Picture))
    WHERE ID = @ID
```

Comment: I don't mind a downvote if I'm wrong. I do however dislike anonymous downvotes with no explanation. Can you explain your objection?

Comment: This seems totally unrelated to the problem. It's not a problem on SQLServer, but a problem on Telerik's ORM. He can't pass a `byte[]` to the procedure. He can however send a `null`, proving the problem is on the ORM.

Comment: @BrunoLM: Thanks for the feedback. It's certainly possible that I've misunderstood the problem. That will be for the OP to determine. I thought I was offering a reasonable work around that could at least be *tried*.

Comment: `But when calling from the GetSqlQuery method with something on the byte[] the transaction says it's not active and not dirty. BUT if the byte[] is null it works as it should.`. How he is supposed to pass `@Picture` if the method will not work?

Comment: @BrunoLM: Looking at the edit history on the question, those details were added *after* I posted my answer.

Comment: He actually described this behavior before the edit. `it seems to be a problem with the VARBINARY. I am passing a byte[] to it, but then it doesn't work. If I send this parameter as NULL it works.`

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli: Hi, thanks for your answer but, my problem is not in procedure. Its a problem when i send a `byte[]`, it doesnt crashes when i send `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Example (Ado.Net):

```
byte[] ba = UlongsToBytes(ul);
try
{
string source = @"packet size=4096;integrated security=SSPI;data source=MyPC\MyNamedInstance;persist security info=False;initial catalog=Sandbox";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(source);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand a = new SqlCommand("INSERT BigintsTarget(bi) SELECT * FROM dbo.ParseImageIntoBIGINTs(@BIGINTs)", conn);
a.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
a.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BIGINTs", System.Data.SqlDbType.Image,2147483647));
for(int q=0; q<10; q++)
{
a.Parameters[0].Value = ba;
int res = a.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
d2 = DateTime.Now;
SqlCommand b = new SqlCommand("INSERT BigintsTarget1(bi) SELECT * FROM dbo.ParseVarcharMAXIntoBIGINTs(@BIGINTs)", conn);
b.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
b.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BIGINTs", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,2147483647));
for(int q=0; q<10; q++)
{
b.Parameters[0].Value = sss;
int res = b.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
//b.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
string s = ex.Message;
int t=0;
t++;
}

}
```